# Knights Tour - What is the relationship between board size and number of tours?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, knight-tours

I understand that the total number of Knights tours is known for boards up to 8 x 8.

These are: 1, 0, 0, 0, 1728, 6637920, 165575218320, 19591828170979904

As found here: "http://oeis.org/A165134"

Could some please explain the relationship between those numbers, or how they are increasing in relation to how board size increases.

Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636/how-many-knights-tours-are-there may help

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  These numbers have no known formula, either explicit or recursive.  That's why the OEIS sequence only goes up to $n=8$.  It's not even obvious that they are increasing for $n > 8$.

Comment: @Shailesh that one seems less general the OP talked about 64 squares ( aka 8 by 8)